# SSLv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, python-2.6

I am using python 2.6 on Debian 6.0 and getting the following traceback

```
File "/home/pwal/api/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/APNSWrapper/notifications.py", line 194, in notify
apnsConnection.connect(apnsHost, self.apnsPort) 

File "/home/pwal/api/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 215, in connect
self.context().connect(host, port)

File "/home/pwal/api/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 161, in connect
self.connectionContext.connect((host, port))

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 295, in connect
self.do_handshake()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 279, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()

SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:490: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Can someone help me what should I do to solve this error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is due to the recent OpenSSL SSL v3 vulnerability known as Poodle.

Apple (and many others) have disabled SSL v3 but APNSWrapper explicitly uses SSL v3.

Never fear the fix is easy. Change this line of code:

```
ssl_version = self.ssl_module.PROTOCOL_SSLv3,
```

to read:

```
ssl_version = self.ssl_module.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
```

At `APNSWrapper/connection.py` line 131.

Make sure to restart any running processes so the new code gets compiled.

Also remember you are updating a package not your own code so if you reinstall the APNSWrapper package on another server you will need to re-patch.  Good Luck!

Comment: You saved my day @Jason Leidigh

Comment: This led me to find "apns-client" has the same problem, fixed by replacing line 41 in backends/stdio.py with `context = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)` Thank you!